# I am using pymongo used mapreduced function to get result but I want alternative for map reduce like group

Tags: mongodb, count, pymongo

```
"tags" : ["MongoDB", "Map/Reduce", "Recipe"]

m = Code("function () {""  this.tags.forEach(function(z) {""    emit(z, 1);""  });""}")

r = Code("function (key, values) {var count = 0;for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {count += values[i];}return count;}")

db.coll.map_reduce(m,r, out = "map_tags",query={"tags": {"$ne": ''},"organization":orgid},safe=True)
```

I can get correct result by above code but I need alternative solution for this.
Because `map_reduce` creating more collections in my db.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the results of a map-reduce persisted then use [`inline_map_reduce`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.inline_map_reduce) instead of `map_reduce`:

```
results = db.coll._inline_map_reduce(m, r, query={"tags": {"$ne": ''}, "organization":orgid}, safe=True)
```

Note that you can only use this approach if your result set fits within the 16MB limit of a single document.